# Python3: conditional expanding of arguments

Tags: python, python-3.x, arguments, parameter-passing

I have a class method `bar` that takes a defined number of arguments:

```py
class Foo:
    
    def bar(self, a: int, b: int):
        return a + b
```

**Edit:**

My goal is to map this function over a cluster with the help of a function coming from a third party module (let's call it `baz`).

The `baz` function would execute `bar` in parallel on the cluster. It takes a function and an iterable of arguments as function input:

```py
def baz(func: Any,
        its: Iterable[Any]):
    ...
```

essentially performing `(func(x) for x in its)` but in parallel on a cluster.

The issue is, when executed, it takes *exactly one argument* from the iterable and passes it to the function supplied. Being a third party function, I can't modify it apart from getting it into my codebase and changing it up.

My question is, how can I best modify / wrap / decorate `bar` so it can be called as is (with the two inputs `a` and `b`), but also used with `baz` which will likely involve expanding a single input tuple into the function arguments `a` and `b`?

Here's one attempt on a simple wrapper function `biz`:

```py
class Foo:
    
    def bar(self, a: int, b: int):
        return a + b
    
    def biz(self, *args):
        
        if len(args) == 1:
            args, = args
        
        return self.bar(*args)
```

With works as expected but seems a bit crude. Also likely confusing and not robust ...

Comment: I think you're going to need to give the context, this currently seems a lot like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Where does `baz` come from, and why can it only handle a single parameter? Right now it looks like `baz(lambda args: foo.bar(*args), ...)` might work, but whether that is the _best_ solution we don't have enough information to be confident.

Comment: @jonrsharpe point taken, tried to simplify as much as possible but seemingly arrived at a point which only looks simple to me. I've edited for clarity, hopefully that improves the Q. thanks.

Comment: Your `biz` function is a workable approach. If you are worried about brittleness, consider some extra validation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I've settled on using a decorator, which handles the requirement quite nicely IMO:

```py
from functools import wraps

class Foo:

    def maybe_expand(func):
        """decorator to expand args if needed"""
        @wraps(func)
        def wrapped(inst, *args):
            if len(args) == 1 and isinstance(args[0], tuple):
                args, = args
            return func(inst, *args)
        return wrapped
    
    @maybe_expand
    def bar(self, a: int, b: int):
        return a + b

foo = Foo()

print(foo.bar(1,2))
# 3

print(foo.bar((1,2)))
# 3
```